# Does XAMPP Lite still exist? Are there any alternatives?

Tags: xampp

As in the title: Where can I find XAMPP Lite distributions for Windows? The [Apache Friends](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) website doesn't host it anymore.

If not, are there any comparable alternatives?

I would like to keep my development environment sync'ed from my NAS in order to work on it on every machine - Synchronization takes too much time when there are 5000+ files which require an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check WampServer:
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

You can still download Lite by going straight to the [Sourceforge project files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/), but it seems that a build for 1.7.4 never happened. You can grab for 1.7.3 there if you want, though.
A few forum threads have already been opened asking about it, but no response from the devs.

URL for forum search: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=lite&fid[]=16 (It's being ignored/stripped by the answer textarea, for some reason when I try to make a proper link with it.)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, here is another alternative:
http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out the Lite or Web-Installer of the [WPN-XM Server Stack](http://wpn-xm.org/).